# Using HTML / UTF-8 character's as cursor

Tags: html, css, utf-8

I'd like to be able use the double arrow characters as a cursor when an image is hovered. Can I only add an image as a custom cursor?

```css
cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
```

http://designerstoolbox.com/designresources/html/

Comment: Do your research. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Yeah cursors can only be images. You can make a png with the characters.

Comment: You can also accomplish this with Javascript.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a solution with an inline SVG:

you can adjust the height and width as you need for your Text (Character). You might also want to change the y of the text for diffrent chars.

```css
html {height:100%;}
body {width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0;
  
  /* only this is relevant */
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="30" style="font-size: 20px;"><text y="15">¶</text></svg>'), auto;
  
}
```

While this is pure CSS, you can also make a HTML5-Canvas and draw your text on it with JavaScript:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
canvas.width = 10
canvas.height = 15
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
context.font = "20px 'sans serif'"
context.fillText("¶", 0, 13)
document.body.style.cursor = "url('" + canvas.toDataURL() + "'), auto"
```

```css
html {height:100%;}
body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;}
```

Comment: Pretty cool, but can  you show an example of how you could use the `canvas` as the `url()` property to set the cursor?

Comment: Ahh, thanks, had a brain fart, now I remember I've used it before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Awesome, I was just trying to edit your answer to add that same example, but I wasn't adding `auto` and it wasn't working :p

Comment: You can also use the SVG trick with Javascript fairly easily: `var repl_cursor='url(\'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="30" style="font-size: 20px;"><text y="15">REPL</text></svg>\'), auto';` `document.body.style.cursor=repl_cursor.replace('REPL','¶');`