# Using Unicode Emoji as a Cursor

Tags: html, css, unicode

Is it possible to do have an Unicode Emoji cursor without having to convert it to an image?
This is the emoji "☠️"
, I want it to become the default cursor, replacing the arrow.
It works using the image (https://image.ibb.co/kSQHi6/cursor.png)
but I don't want to use an image.

**DEMO using PNG**

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  cursor:url(https://image.ibb.co/kSQHi6/cursor.png), auto;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE DEMO:**https://jsfiddle.net/2zp1v56y/

Comment: You could hide the cursor and make the emoji follow your mouse position by using Javascript.

Comment: @Maharkus I am not too confident with javascript, how would this be implemented?

Comment: You dont. It will never feel as smooth as a cursor does

Comment: I just googled the javascript solution. Its not smooth at all.

Comment: I just made a code snippet in the answers, you can check for yourself, if it's good enough for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Javascript solution I proposed earlier on, where I hid the mouse cursor and put an element on top of it with the emoji on it.

Performancewise you'll have to decide yourself if it suffices.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#cursor').css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  cursor: none;
}
.box:hover + #cursor {
  display: block;
}

#cursor {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute; 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is the emoji "☠️"</p>
<p>I want it to become the default cursor, replacing the arrow</p>
<p>
It works using the image (https://image.ibb.co/kSQHi6/cursor.png)
</p>
<div class="box"></div>
<div id="cursor">☠️</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found a way to do it with pure CSS.

Comment: How did you add it purely with CSS? ;) ty

Comment: @BirdieGolden https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685391/using-html-utf-8-characters-as-cursor